# Google Actions - UTF-8 decoding when using AWS API Gateway

Tags: utf-8, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, actions-on-google

I'm working on my first Action on Google and having a headache trying to work out how to display unicode characters in my basic card and the spoken text.

For example "Beyoncé" renders as "BeyoncÃ©" in the simulator and on my phone.

The data is coming from my Amazon API Gateway, which returns the result of my Lambda. The logging here shows the correct format, so I guess my Action isn't set up correctly?

Interestingly, emojis don't render either (hard-coded in the same lambda). Having followed this guide https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#rich-responses so I must be missing some configuration?

Im my DialogFlow Fulfilment setup for the Webhook, I've set the charset to UTF-8 and Content-Type to application/json

Is there anything else to configure?

Comment: Hey @jewkesy, did you find the solution to this issue ?

Comment: Hey @QuentinDel, not yet.  Currently chatting with DialogFlow support on this, they have advised me to investigate why the response headers has no "charset=UTF-8" in "content-type", though it is send on the request.  Currently trawling the AWS documentation to understand where the further configuration is needed and how to correctly apply it

Comment: @jewkesy have you found a solution any more? I am getting the same issue?

Comment: @AntonioCucciniello, yep - just updated the post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My resolution was to add further configuration settings to my AWS API Gateway. It appears that DialogFlow v2 no longer assumes (or defaults to?) the utf-8 charset for the web hook response.

Just add `content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` to your method response header, rather than relying on this value being persisted from the request header.

[image: Method Response Content Setting]

Comment: glad to hear its fixed! is this something you do in API Gateway? or in your code? Also if you could provide an example that would help!

Comment: @AntonioCucciniello Sure!  Added a screenshot showing where the setting needs to be applied in API Gateway

Comment: worked great. the exact string is "pplication/json; charset=UTF-8"